# Generating .dll files with dllwrap for Visual Studio 2012 (ARPACK)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dll

I am trying to make .lib file of ARPACK library to use with VS2012 Express Edition. Hence I am using the command in MSYS as :

> dllwrap --export-all-symbols BLAS/*.o LAPACK/*.o SRC/*.o UTIL/*.o
>   -lgfortran --output-def arpack_win32.def -o arpack_win32.dll

This results in error:

> real_write' UTIL/smout.o:smout.f:(.text+0x12cf): undefined reference
>   to `_gfortran_transfer_ array_write'
>   UTIL/smout.o:smout.f:(.text+0x12f1): undefined reference to`
>   _gfortran_transfer_ integer_write'
>   UTIL/smout.o:smout.f:(.text+0x13b4): undefined reference to
>   `_gfortran_transfer_ integer_write'
>   UTIL/smout.o:smout.f:(.text+0x13ef): undefined reference to`
>   _gfortran_transfer_ real_write' UTIL/smout.o:smout.f:(.text+0x1581):
>   undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_ array_write'
>   UTIL/smout.o:smout.f:(.text+0x15a3): undefined reference to`
>   _gfortran_transfer_ integer_write'
>   UTIL/smout.o:smout.f:(.text+0x1666): undefined reference to
>   `_gfortran_transfer_ integer_write'
>   UTIL/smout.o:smout.f:(.text+0x16a1): undefined reference to`
>   _gfortran_transfer_ real_write' UTIL/svout.o:svout.f:(.text+0xb4):
>   undefined reference to `_gfortran_transfer_ch aracter_write'
>   UTIL/svout.o:svout.f:(.text+0xd2): undefined reference to`
>   _gfortran_transfer_ch aracter_write'
>   UTIL/svout.o:svout.f:(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to
>   `_gfortran_transfer_i nteger_write'
>   UTIL/svout.o:svout.f:(.text+0x1cd): undefined reference to`
>   _gfortran_transfer_i nteger_write'

Cant figure it out why this happens....Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out what was wrong....I was using MinGW with gfortran..... Adding C:\MinGW\bin to PATH solved all the issues.....